# How to convert string array to json in android

Tags: android, android-json

Following is my `JSONArray` data  How do I convert this to a `StringArray`?

```
 private void getTextfromalledittext()
    {
       String textpoint[]=new String[editTextList.size()];
       int i=0;
       for(EditText editText:editTextList)
       {
            textpoint[i]=editText.getText().toString();
            i++;
       }

   }
```

Comment: Hi, please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert String array to json in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327640/convert-string-array-to-json-in-android)

Comment: show the example of the input data and output you want from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement like this -

```
private void getTextfromalledittext(){
   String textpoint[]=new String[editTextList.size()];
   int i=0;
   for (EditText editText:editTextList) {
       textpoint[i]=editText.getText().toString();
       i++;
   }
   JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(textpoint));
}
```